# Impala shell error kerberos gives me an error

Tags: kerberos, impala

When I run impal-shell -k, and I want to create a table, it displays the following error:

```
[localhost:21000] default> CREATE TABLE example (edad INTEGER);
Query: CREATE TABLE example (edad INTEGER)
ERROR: ImpalaRuntimeException: Error making 'createTable' RPC to Hive Metastore: 
CAUSED BY: MetaException: Got exception: java.io.IOException Failed on local exception: java.io.IOException: org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Client cannot authenticate via:[TOKEN, KERBEROS]; Host Details : local host is: "localhost/127.0.0.1"; destination host is: "localhost":20500;
```

I guess that I try to connect to HDFS but it doesn't authenticate. Any ideas on what is happening?

Comment: you may not have access to default schema and syntax error. can you pls try this `CREATE TABLE yourschema.example (edad INT)` after ensuring you have RW access to yourschema.

Comment: ```  [localhost:21000] default> CREATE TABLE default.example (edad INTEGER);
Query: CREATE TABLE default.example (edad INTEGER)
ERROR: ImpalaRuntimeException: Error making 'createTable' RPC to Hive Metastore: 
CAUSED BY: MetaException: Got exception: java.io.IOException Failed on local exception: java.io.IOException: org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Client cannot authenticate via:[TOKEN, KERBEROS]; Host Details : local host is: "localhost/127.0.0.1"; destination host is: "localhost":20500; 
``` doing that gives the same errir

Comment: It may be related to auth because it can't write in default db. Did u chk with uiur hive admin that you have write permission?